# React Router Components not being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this question has been asked tons of times but I can't seem to find a working solution for a very simple problem.

I am setting up a simple Navigation Bar using React Bootstrap and React Router

The page loads on the Home page but when a link is clicked the URL changes but the component does not render. When I inspect using google Chrome, the heading is unchanged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried almost everything I found here, used withRouter, used regular  and

elements instead of the ones from React Bootstrap.

Here is the code, index.js is the regular create-react-app set up

App.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Home } from './components/pages/Home';
import Navibar from './components/Navibar';
import { LostPets } from './components/pages/LostPets';
import { AdoptPets } from './components/pages/AdoptPets';
import { ContactUs } from './components/pages/ContactUs';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      {/* Navigation Bar */}
      <Router>
        <Navibar />  

        {/* Routes for Pages */}
        <Switch>                  
          <Route exact path='/LostPets' component={LostPets}/>  
          <Route exact path='/AdoptPets' component={AdoptPets}/>               
          <Route exact path='/ContactUs' component={ContactUs}/>   
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>   
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Navibar () {
    return(

        <Container>
          <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" sticky="top">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">PETSTT </Navbar.Brand>

            {/* Navigation Bar items */}
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#lostpets">Lost Pets </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#adoptpets">Adopt Me </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#contactus">Contact Us </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar>
        </Container>  

    ); 

}
```

All pages are just header text like this.

```
import React from 'react'; 

export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Home </h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

[image: my file structure if it helps]

Comment: The React Bootstrap `Nav.Link` component is not the same as React Router' `Link` component. You'll have to either set the `history` with the `onChange` on `Nav.Link` or use the `Link` component. And currently the paths on the links and the routes are not matching. They have to be exactly the same, preferebly without uppercases, like `/lostpets`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier is the correct answer. Using href will refresh the page and remount ALL the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Link` is going to the wrong url. You are going to a hash url which would suggest a different section on the same page with that ID.

```
<Nav.Link href="#lostpets">Lost Pets </Nav.Link>
```

This doesn't match the routes that you are trying to render. The routes are done correctly.

```
<Route exact path='/LostPets' component={LostPets}/>
```

You should change the `Link` to this:

```
<Nav.Link href="/LostPets">Lost Pets </Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted but it worked Thanks !!